# Animate a grid to move or slide to the right WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have a grid with elements in it. I want to move all of those elements, so is it not possible to just move the grid all together? This isn't having any effect from what I'm seeing and I've tried even ScaleX and such as well.

```
<Grid x:Name="HancockDetails" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">                       
   <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF30000"/>               
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
      </s:ScatterViewItem>
```

My function:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

DoubleAnimation slide = new DoubleAnimation();
slide.To = 3000.0;
slide.From = 0;
slide.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(40.0));

// Set the target of the animation
Storyboard.SetTarget(slide,HancockDetails);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));

// Kick the animation off
sb.Children.Add(slide);
sb.Begin();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to first add the `RenderTransform` in the markup, otherwise the runtime can't find it:

```
<Grid x:Name="HancockDetails" ...>  
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

I assume you want to use `TranslateTransform`, and not `ScaleTransform`, since the goal is to slide the grid over, not to resize it?

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, 
    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
```

Comment: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.XProperty)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

Comment: @user2229804 can you reference the TranslateTransform directly, as I did above?  I think that's less confusing.  If you can't, then I think the correct syntax would be `"(FrameworkElement).(TranslateTransform.X)"`.

Comment: is it supposed to be surrounded in quotes? It seems either way it doesn't work. Am I missing a directive perhaps?
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement).TranslateTransform.X"));

Comment: And sorry, yeah I cannot reference it directly.

Comment: @user2229804 Sorry ... should be `"(RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"`.  Updated above.

Comment: @user2229804 I guess your syntax was right originally, just needed to add `TranslateTransform` to the markup.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to create a storyboard by hand it is muuuuuuch easier to use *Expression Blend*. Its a free design tool that compliments *Visual Studio*. The storyboard you are explaining would take all of 30 seconds to make there and there would be no code. Then when you wanted it to run it would just be the `StoryBoardName.Begin()`

To easy right? Heres a resource. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc197141.aspx

Comment: I agree it is easy in Blend, but I have to basically create it for every object specifically. And I have a lot of objects I want to move the same way. I'm sure there is a way around it, but it looks to be more complicated then just making a single function no?

Comment: @Nitesh what are you talking about? Blend is an excellent tool for development. As many professionals know, engineers are not UI experts. So when you have to code and design at the same time usually the design falls WAY short. If you can take half of that problem out (the code) then you can focus on what looks correct. Expression Blend is a fantastic tool.

Comment: It is for Designers. Developers rely on VS.

Comment: @Nitesh Well my professional title is Software Developer and I use it all the time for user control creation. It's just another tool in the toolbox. Any mature dev is going to tell you that knowledge is power kimosabi.

Comment: I agree. For this entire project I've been using Blend and Visual Studio. I switch between them constantly. Before, using only VS, it was a horrific nightmare because its an interactive map and I was trying to program functionality into objects that weren't actually visible. It was horrific. Blend is quite the nice compliment to VS when doing visual components and GUIs. It isn't just design when you're trying to play with properties of .NET too.

Comment: Update or remove the link please. :-/